# File check and update

Tags: vb.net

I want to make updater for some files (Like a SVN). So all files are around 250MB and downloading them and comparing with exist files will be too long. I thought to make system, that compares just information about files.For example: get number of bytes from file "a" on hdd and file "a" on a cloud, then compare the numbers and update if needed file on hdd.

So I tried to make it like I said before, but failed. I have some code, but I can't make it done:

```
Private Sub scan()
    Dim path As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim files() As FileInfo
    Dim dirinfo As New DirectoryInfo(path)
    files = dirinfo.GetFiles("*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each file In files
        ListBox1.Items.Add(file.Name & "," & file.Length)
    Next
End Sub
```

I just have a file list in my program and in the cloud, but i can't use it for comparing. Is there any idea how to make it?

Comment: It might be worth it to note that a simple byte count comparison isn't really sufficient to check if a file has any changes made to it (though it might be a reasonably good starting point, in combination with the last changed date...).

Comment: Do you put the files there? If so, can you control the file names? Is this your cloud server written by you, or someone else that can make some new methods for you? What is the cloud service? That usually helps.

Comment: So i use the simplest cloud service - DropBox.